# WebClient Headers on WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, gzip

Please, tell me how can i set headers to webclient?
I try this

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers["Content-Encoding"] = "gzip";
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("..."));
```

But i received exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException. "An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details."

- InnerException  {System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.  ---> System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: A request with this method cannot have a request body.    at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)    at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---} System.Exception {System.Net.WebException}

Comment: Can you post the InnerException?

Comment: As a quick solution, just don't use `WebClient`, use `HttpClient` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ::

```
    webClient.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip";
```

or even this

```
    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip";
```

I even found something like :: WebClient uses HttpWebRequest under the covers. And HttpWebRequest supports gzip/deflate decompression. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.automaticdecompression.aspx

However, WebClient class does not expose this property directly. So you will have to derive from it to set the property on the underlying HttpWebRequest.

```
    class MyWebClient : WebClient
    {
      protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
      {
        HttpWebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        return request;
     }
   }
```

Hope it works :)
Cheers.

Comment: In my WP8.1 Silverlight project, the Property AutomaticDecompression is not available. Any ideas for a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Encoding` header is used to define the encoding of the requests **body**. Since you are making a `GET` reuqest, the problem comes from that a `GET` request **cannot** have a body (as the exception message sais). If you are trying to define the encoding of the **response** then you should use the `Accept-Encoding` header.